# Which community does not allow women to wear make up?

Tags: women, tznius-modesty, communities

I know the neturei karta don't allow women to wear make up. What about other communities? Does Satmar? Does Toldos Aharon?

Comment: Satmar, at least in Williamsburg, allows it. I don't know about Toldos Aharon.

Comment: Can you please source your assumption ?